# Are binary partition trees premade before points are added to nodes?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, search, kdtree

I'm trying to implement [this algorithm](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1505/1505.03090.pdf) in Python, but due to my lack of understanding tree structures I'm confused about creation process of the partition tree.

**Brief Explanation**:

Algorithm that was linked, is for partitioning a high-dimensional feature space into internal and leaf nodes so that query can be performed quickly.

It divides a large space using specific random test, hyperplane that splits one large cell into two.

[This answer explains everything much more precisely](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3044426/513294).

[image]

(taken from the link above)

**Code Fragments**:

```
def random_test(self, main_point):  # Main point is np.ndarray instance
    dimension = main_point.ravel().size
    random_coefficients = self.random_coefficients(dimension)
    scale_values = np.array(sorted([np.inner(random_coefficients, point.ravel())
                                    for point in self.points]))
    percentile = random.choice([np.percentile(scale_values, 100 * self.ratio),  # Just as described on Section 3.1
                                np.percentile(scale_values, 100 * (1 - self.ratio))])
    main_term = np.inner(main_point.ravel(), random_coefficients)
    if self.is_leaf():
        return 0  # Next node is the center leaf child
    else:
        if (main_term - percentile) >= 0:  # Hyper-plane equation defined in the document
            return -1  # Next node is the left child
        else:
            return 1  # Next node is the right child
```

`self.ratio` as mentioned in the algorithm linked above, is determining how balanced and shallow the tree will be, at `1/2` it is supposed to generate the most balanced and shallow tree.

Then we move onto the iterative part, where the tree keeps dividing the space further and further until it **reaches** the leaf node (notice the keyword **reaches**), the problem is, it will **never truly** reaches the leaf node.

Since, the definition of leaf node in the document linked above is this:

```
def is_leaf(self):
    return (self.capacity * self.ratio) <= self.cell_count() <= self.capacity
```

where `self.cell_count()` is number of points in the cell, `self.capacity` is the maximum amount of points that the cell can have and `self.ratio` is the split ratio.

[My full code](https://github.com/ShellRox/Lucifitas/blob/master/core/semantic/polyconvex.py) should basically divide the feature space by creating new nodes at initial iteration until the leaf node is created (but the leaf node is never created). [See the fragment that contains the division process](https://github.com/ShellRox/Lucifitas/blob/master/core/semantic/polyconvex.py/#L230-L256).

[image]

(taken from the document linked above)

## tl;dr:

Are binary partition trees prepared (filled with empty nodes) before we add any points to them? If so, don't we require to define the level (depth) of the tree?

**If not**, are binary partition trees created while adding points to them? If so, then how is the first point (from the first iteration) added to the tree?

Comment: Seems like you're attempting to do [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning#Generation).

Comment: @user3386109 I've already seen that, but I couldn't find answer to my question. Algorithm linked aboce was described quite implicitly but I think I'm starting to understand it. I believe points should not be dropped to the tree separately in different levels, instead, all points in the parent node should be dropped at every level of the tree. I'll try that out, perhaps this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are built as you go along. The first node is right or left of line 1. Then the next level asks right or left of line 2... your illustration from the provided paper shows this with the lines being numbered in association with the choice presented for finding the node.

Ofcourse right or left is not accurate. Some lines are cut horizontally. But the spaces created are binary.

Comment: My apologies for late response, I've tried that method as mentioned in the comments and it worked perfectly fine. I will make a new answer anyway explaining how, if anybody requires that.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to test the new method as mentioned in the comments, and it worked perfectly fine.

[The algorithm that was linked above](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1505/1505.03090.pdf), implicitly states that the point shall be individually dropped down into the partition tree, passing all the random tests and creating new nodes as it is dropped down.

---

But there is a significant problem with this method, since in order to have a balanced efficient and shallow tree, left and right nodes must be distributed evenly.

Hence, in order to split the node, at every level of the tree, every point of the node must be passed to either left or right node (by a random test), until the tree reaches the depth where all nodes at that level are leaf.

---

In mathematical terms, root node contains a vector space which is divided into two left and right nodes containing convex polyhedrons bounded by supporting hyper-planes by the separating hyper-plane:

[image]

Negative term of the equation (I believe we can call it bias), is where the splitting ratio starts to play, it should be percentile of all node points between 100*r to 100*(1-r), so that tree is separated more evenly and it is more shallow. Basically it decides how even should hyper-plane separation be, that's why we require nodes that contain all the points.

---

I have been able to implement such system:

```
def index_space(self):
    shuffled_space = self.shuffle_space()
    current_tree = PartitionTree()
    level = 0
    root_node = RootNode(shuffled_space, self.capacity, self.split_ratio, self.indices)
    current_tree.root_node = root_node
    current_tree.node_array.append(root_node)
    current_position = root_node.node_position
    node_array = {0: [root_node]}
    while True:
        current_nodes = node_array[level]
        if all([node.is_leaf() for node in current_nodes]):
            break
        else:
            level += 1
            node_array[level] = []
            for current_node in current_nodes:
                if not current_node.is_leaf():
                    left_child = InternalNode(self.capacity, self.split_ratio, self.indices,
                                              self._append(current_position, [-1]), current_node)
                    right_child = InternalNode(self.capacity, self.split_ratio, self.indices,
                                               self._append(current_position, [1]), current_node)
                    for point in current_node.list_points():
                        if current_node.random_test(point) == 1:
                            right_child.add_point(point)
                        else:
                            left_child.add_point(point)
                    node_array[level].extend([left_child, right_child])
```

where `node_array` contains all the nodes of the tree (root, internal and leaf).

Unfortunately, `node.random_test(x)` method:

```
def random_test(self, main_point):
    random_coefficients = self.random_coefficients()
    scale_values = [np.inner(self.random_coefficients(), point[:self.indices].ravel())
                                    for point in self.points]
    percentile = np.percentile(scale_values, self.ratio * 100)
    main_term = np.inner(main_point[:self.indices].ravel(), random_coefficients)
    if self.is_leaf():
        return 0  # Next node is the center leaf child
    else:
        if (main_term - percentile) >= 0:  # Hyper-plane equation defined in the document
            return -1  # Next node is the left child
        else:
            return 1  # Next node is the right child
```

is inefficient, since calculating percentile takes too much time. Hence I have to find another way to calculate percentile (perhaps by performing short-circuited binary search to optimize percentile).

---

## Conclusion:

This is just a large extension of Clinton Ray Mulligan's answer - which briefly explains the solution to create such trees and hence will remain as an accepted answer.

I have just added more details in case anyone is interested in implementing randomized binary partition trees.

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer. I appreciate the more elaborate explaination. For others who may want some foundational reading, the paper as linked is a varient of Binary Space Partitioning. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning The technique is used extensively in random generated levels of sprite games. Example of such code in Pythin available http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_Python%2Blibtcod,_extras#BSP_Dungeon_Generator